# Ran out of registers xcode c++

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to build a project with address sanitizer using XCode 13.0. During the build I get the following error:

`Ran out of registers during register allocation`

What are the possible causes of this problem? It seems that there is few information about this error on the internet.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide source code as I wasn't to able to reproduce it with small sample and original problem is with my work project.

Comment: Is this an optimising build?  If so, turning optimisation off may resolve it.  Moved on from Xcode 12 I see :)

Comment: Short answer is "compiler bug", but there's a good chance you can work around by simplifying your code and/or adjusting optimization options.  Without more details we can't guess how.

Comment: In principle it could be your bug instead of the compiler, if you have something like an inline asm requesting an impossible number of registers. Though in some sense, modern inline asm is effectively writing a compiler extension, so it's not too far off to lump that in with "compiler bug".